# Jquery - coloring the background of all id

Tags: jquery, css, background-color

In the html file below, the jquery is not coloring the background of all `id="0"`.
The jquery this only coloring the only the first id.
How can I make all `id="0"` are colored with jquery?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" style="padding-top: 15px;" id="0">0</td>       
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" style="padding-top: 15px;" id="0">0</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("td#0").css("background-color", "rgba(201, 221, 237, 0.99)");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: ids are suppose to be unique in a page. use class instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An id has to be unique to work properly. When you try find elements with a duplicate id, the browser will only give you one of them.

You should use a different way of finding the elements, for example adding a class to the elements, or putting the id on the table and use that to select the cells in it.

For completeness, it's actually still possible to find all the elements with a duplicate id, but then you have to treat it as an attribute:

```
$("td[id='0']").css("background-color", "rgba(201, 221, 237, 0.99)");
```

You should of course only use that if you can't change the HTML code, and the id is the only way to select the elements.